# Count values in dataframe based on entry

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
category | value |
cat a    |x      |
cat a    |x      |
cat a    |y      |
cat b    |w      |
cat b    |z      |
```

I'd like to be able to return something like (showing unique values and frequency)

```
category | freq of most common value |most common value |
cat a       2                              x
cat b       1                              w #(it doesnt matter if here is an w or z)
```

Comment: What approach did you take and what went wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.head.html) per groups in lambda function:

```
df = (df.groupby('category', sort=False)['value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1))
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'level_1':'most_common_value','value':'freq of most common value'}))
print (df)
  category most_common_value  freq of most common value
0    cat a                 x                          2
1    cat b                 w                          1
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to `groupby` both columns and take the `size`, sort the values and take the one with higher frequency:

```
(df.groupby(['category', 'value'])
   .value.size()
   .sort_values()
   .groupby(level=0)
   .tail(1))
```

---

```
category  value
cat b      z        1
cat a      x        2
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: yop, maybe reset index and renaming should be necessary too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `crosstab`:

```
m = pd.crosstab(df['category'],df['value'])
m = m.max(1).to_frame('freq of most common value').assign(most_common_value=m.idxmax(1))
```

---

```
print(m)

          freq of most common value most_common_value
category                                             
cat a                             2                 x
cat b                             1                 w
```