# Find maximum in Dataframe based on variable values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
A| B| C | D
a| x| r | 1
a| x| s | 2
a| y| r | 1
b| w| t | 4
b| z| v | 2
```

I'd like to be able to return something like (showing unique values and frequency)

```
A| freq of most common value in Column B |maximum of column D based on the most common value in Column B | most common value in Column B
a       2                                                  2                                                           x
b       1                                                  4                                                           w
```

at the moment i can calculate the everything but the 3 column of the result dataframe quiet fast via

```
df = (df.groupby('A', sort=False)['B']
    .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1))
    .reset_index()
```

but to calculate the 2 Column ("maximum of column D based on the most common value in Column B") i have writen a for-loop witch is slow for a lot of data. 
Is there a fast way?

The question is linked to: [Count values in dataframe based on entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59646659/count-values-in-dataframe-based-on-entry)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with get rows by maximum `D` per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby('A', sort=False)['B']
        .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1))
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'level_1':'E'}))
#print (df1)

df = df1.merge(df, left_on=['A','E'], right_on=['A','B'], suffixes=('','_'))
df = df.loc[df.groupby('A')['D'].idxmax(), ['A','B','D','E']]
print (df)
   A  B  D  E
1  a  2  2  x
2  b  1  4  w
```

Comment: nice use of idxmax() inside loc(). I like this solution!

Answer (score 2):

Consider doing this in 3 steps:

1. find most common B (as in your code):

`df2 = (df.groupby('A', sort=False)['B']).apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1)).reset_index()`

2. build DataFrame with max D for each combination of A and B

`df3 = df.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'D':max}).reset_index()`

3. merge 2 DataFrames to find max Ds matching the A-B pairs selected earlier

`df2.merge(df3, left_on=['A','level_1'], right_on=['A','B'])`

The column D in the resulting DataFrame will be what you need

```
   A level_1  B_x B_y  D
0  a       x    2   x  2
1  b       w    1   w  4
```